# Android NDK best practice

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-ndk

For some time I'm developing for Android in IntelliJ Idea. Sometimes using jni and always its pretty uncomfortable.

Please suggest the best way to make Idea do ​such things with C/C++

- syntax highlighting
- auto-completion
- indexing sources and provide "usages of member" or "go to declaration" links

Ideally, it would be very cool to show error messages in idea and show line in code with error like for java.
I believe there is a couple of good soluthions. Perhaps in Eclipse? Or in Emacs >< ?

UPD. Ok, what i actually have found by myself is Sequoyah, n-vidia ndk debug in MVS, c++ plugin in idea and ndk-stack in iTerm. I'tried all except n-vidia. And all of that was unsatisfactorily. Is this all solutions? Perhaps there is some man about proper tune-uo?

Comment: "Best practice" is to use Eclipse if at all possible, and code in Java whenever possible :)

Comment: I'd submit that the "best practice" for multiplatform projects involves reusing code between mobile platforms. Thus, NDK. Also, referring to "best practices" all too often becomes an excuse to start a cargo cult.

Answer (score 1):

Never tried them, but the [Sequoyah Project](http://www.aton.com/integrating-the-android-ndk-c-native-support-into-eclipse-using-sequoyah/) seems to be all about integrating NDK development with Eclipse.

Comment: 99% of my NDK code is ported from Windows Mobile and iOS (save the Java glue code). By the time it gets to Android, it's fairly well-debugger. So I build by calling `ndk-build` from the Cygwin command line and debug by writing variables to LogCat.

Comment: Sequoyah is dead. It was largely a Motorola initiative and it has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Well, almost year passed, but still i have not discover nothing better than debug-print and GDB in extreme cases. GDB is rather easy to use, but pretty uncomfortable.

Every special IDE or plugin looks as not a real solution. Hope, that announced Android Studio will help, when reaches release stage.